# How to integerate WordPress Mail SMTP plugin to Report and Request custom page

Tags: email

Since a week ago, WordPress stopped to send normal emails upon new events like new user registration, new comments, and sucuri logs.

I tried everything but no luck, so i installed WP Mail SMTP to connect Gmail to my WordPress with Google API and it works fine.

But i have custom pages (Report and Request) that depends on default WordPress PHP mailer

so, how i integrate WP Mail SMTP inside these pages

here is an example of the report page

```
<?php 
if($_GET['report']) { 
require_once "form/captacha.php";
$siteKey = get_option('pc_key');
$secret = get_option('pv_key');
$resp = null;
$error = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
$resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"] ); }
if ($resp != null && $resp->success) { 
require("form/class.phpmailer.php");
$msg = "";
if ($_POST['action'] == "send") {
$vname = $_FILES['arch']['name'];
$vtemp = $_FILES['arch']['tmp_name'];
$rmailsend = get_option('reportemail');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->From = $rmailsend;
$mail->FromName = __( "New Report", "demotheme" );
$mail->Subject = $_POST['videos'];
$mail->AddAddress($rmailsend);
if ($vname != "") {
$mail->AddAttachment($vtemp, $vname); }
$body = "body"
```

and here is the "class.phpmailer.php" file https://justpaste.it/683q8

Comment: WordPress uses PHP Mailer also... just change your code to use wp_mail function instead of using it separately and it will send via SMTP plugin fine. :-)

Comment: Thnx for ur comment, but how to change the code to use wp_mail function

Comment: in the last lines of your code instead of the `$mail` object just put the variables as arguments, eg. `wp_mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers=array(), $attachment);` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: Although it takes me some time to figure it out. But i finally did it after you show me the right way, Thanks a lot.

Comment: awesome glad I could help. :-)